# Splitting one text-field into two with Javascript, validate it, then merge it back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

A client is asking that a textfield containing phone-number data be split into two -- one for country code, the other for the rest of the number.

Alas, this field is pretty hard-coded into the system and all data collected thus far has been as one consolidated field (and thus saved as one column in the database).

I'm thus thinking the best answer might be to do the following:

1. Using Javascript, replace the single text field with two text fields.
2. These then become merged back into the original text field when the user clicks the submit button.
3. Bonus marks if there's a way to separate that field back into two again when it's read from the database (I.e., when an administrator views the entry). Note that the data format must be consistent -- I don't want to mix the existing string data with, say, a bunch of JSON strings.

Is this the best way to go about this? Are there any foreseeable problems (beyond the user not having JavaScript enabled) with this approach? Is there a jQuery plugin that's designed to do stuff like this?

I also need to validate it as a valid phone number at some point, but I can figure that out myself.

Comment: Do all the numbers in the database have country codes? Or is it only going forwards?

Comment: @RemarkLima They already do AFAIK. I think the client is just wanting it as an aesthetic thing to ensure people enter proper country codes and whathaveyou.

Comment: @JayBlanchard NothingYetThatIsWhyIamAskingForAdviceAndToAskWhetherThereIsAnEasierWay-ForInstanceAjQueryPlugin-OrIfIamOver-orUnder-thinkingItIamNotAskingForAFullyCodedSolutionHere.com

Comment: And then, if every entry has a country code, are they all standard? Are they all +44 / +1 / +64 or are some 0044 / 001 / 0064? Do they all have a space after them? If they do have a space it'll be a trivial matter to pull out the country code by the first index of a space... But really depends on the quality of the data.

Comment: @RemarkLima There'll be a + before the form so that it's just country and area code in the first box, remainder of the number in the second.  But yeah, it's a difficult thing to get consistent data for.

Comment: Personally, first thing I'd look to do is ETL the data into a normalised format, even if it's in one field that it's 100% consistent. Then you know what you're working with - At the moment, it sounds like anything could throw it out, be it brackets for the area code, spaces between area code and country code, no spaces anywhere etc... Then you can mask the input when new enteries go into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use a plugin you can always check out this snippet I made on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVSJN/)

If you want to make sure it works in the JS just change the display:'none' to display:'block'

here is my JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('#phone').css({ display:'none' });
    $('#phone').after(') <input type="text" name="phoneMainNumber" id="phoneMainNumber" />').after('(<input type="text" value="555" name="phoneAreaCode" id="phoneAreaCode" style="width:30px;" />');
    bindChange();
});

function bindChange() {
    $('#phone').val('('+$('#phoneAreaCode').val()+') ');
    $('#phoneMainNumber, #phoneAreaCode').keyup(function() {
       $('#phone').val('('+$('#phoneAreaCode').val()+') '+$('#phoneMainNumber').val());    
    });   
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was thinking. I don't think it'd be that easy to pull it back into that format from database given the varying lengths of international telephone numbers, but it's probably more important that it's consistent on the end-user side rather than the administrator side. Thanks!

Comment: Well can you give me an example of some numbers you would expect to get. I should help me better script this for you.

Comment: It's international phone numbers, so anything from +44(0)nnnnnnnnnnn to +1(403)nnnnnnn (The first one the zero is dropped if calling internationally; in the second, the 403 bit is kept if calling internationally. Why? Because phone numbers are stupid.). Really, the first box will contain the `+nn(nnn)` part (With the + being outside of the field), the second will contain the rest of the number. I'll probably need to use a filter plugin for the validation so that only numbers and parenthesis can be used.

Comment: So it would actually be best if the phone was split into three different inputs.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm content with it just being two, really.

Comment: Eh, forgot to save my jsfiddle earlier. That simplified version of your code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/62G4V/2/

Answer (score 2):

Rather than splitting the text field into two, you may use the masked input JQuery plug-in

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#phone").mask("(999)999999");                
});
```

Sample JS : http://jsfiddle.net/vGeMV/3/

Edit: 
For point 3 : If you want to really split the number into two and display it, you may split it from the right (usually 7 digits) rather than left so that even if country code is present or not, you will get the correct split.

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers the question, but that is a really neat plugin.